# Is It possible to install a driver using visual studio setup project?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, driver, setup-project

I need to make a setup.exe for a kernel driver.
The setup project only complies it to a sys file.
 Is it possible to run the inf file using the setup project, or installing it properly some other way?
I am using visual studio 2015 setup project.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I believe the most common way people do this with a Visual Studio setup project is to use DPInst.exe, as Install and Uninstall custom actions in your setup. This example uses WiX but it gives you some info about how DPInst works:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/44191/Drivers-Installation-With-WiX